# How to do a Collection of integer pairs?

Tags: java, android

How to do this with collection support? I tried `HashMap` but it is not suitable. I need to get in a result for example: {(1,0),(1,2),(3,5)}

```
ArrayList<int[][]> list = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
int[][] pair = new int[1][1];
    pair[0][0] = (Integer) key;
    pair[0][1] = (Integer) value;
    list.add(pair);
}
```

Comment: You are already doing it. Concept is correct. But it won't compile

Comment: What's wrong with `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`?

Comment: you might just create a class `Pair` which has two fields and return a list of it.

Comment: `{(1,0),(1,2),(3,5)}` seems to store different values for the same key, so a `Map` is not viable (keys are unique). You should make your own `Pair<S, T>` class with `<Integer, Integer>` parameter. Or just a Pair that stores ints. Whichever suits you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pair is a proper structure for your needs. Use it like this:

```
import android.util.Pair;

List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    list.add(new Pair(key, value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use standard java `java.awt.Point`.
Nothing additional needed.

like

```
Vector<Point> myVec = new Vector<Point>;
```

you can still use these 2D Points like

```
int key;
int value;

Point point = new Point(key, value);
myVec.add(point);
```

and if you want to check the entries for a spec element

```
for(Point p : myVec)
{
  if(p[0] == searchKey) //...do something 
}
```

Comment: May be this is overkill, but I want to add: there is class [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) in Apache Commons Lang.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Point` API.

```
import android.graphics.Point;

ArrayList<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();

for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    list.add(new Point(key, value));
}
```